# Access Files From Another Docker Container - Same Network

Tags: docker, express, docker-compose, multer

I need help. I have an expressjs REST API that uplodas files using multer running in a container using docker-compose, and another front end app on another container. How can i access the uploaded files from the front end?

```
version: '2'
services:
   api:
container_name: "api"
restart: always
build:
  context: ./api
ports:
  - "8383:8383"
environment:
  - test=testvalue

networks:
  - pms

app:
container_name: "app"
restart: always
build:
  context: ./app
ports:
  - "7777:80"
environment:
  - test=testvalue

networks:
  - pms

 networks:
  pms:
```

Comment: do you mean that you upload the file to the backend service?

Comment: If you make an HTTP POST to send the files to the back-end, I'd probably use an HTTP GET to retrieve them; this would be part of your back-end's HTTP API.  This is especially true if the front-end is a browser application using a framework like React; but even so, each container has a separate filesystem and it's better design to not try to share files.

Comment: yes i mean that @dannykaplunski

Comment: I understand @DavidMaze thank you